# How to convert a number into a string in Maple?

Tags: maple

I want to have something like this code from Python

```py
num=3
res=str(num)
```

but in Maple. I couldn't find any appropriate constructors for this. Are there any?

Answer (score 3):

```
num:=3:

convert(num,string);

               "3"

sprintf("%a",num);

               "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `convert` as already exists in @acer's answer. Just to name one more possibility here is another way.

```
num := 3:
res := cat( "", num );
```

You will get `"3"` for `res` of type `string`. What `cat` here does is concatenating `3` to the empty string `""`, and when there exists at least one string in the arguments of `cat`, the output becomes a string. You can even have something like `sqrt(2)` instead of `3` in `num`, in that case `res` becomes this string; `"2^(1/2)"`. But sometimes it may give you a non-string object, for example if the number in `num` is of the form `RootOf`. See the help page to read more.